# AWS CDK - Stop Generating Policies

Tags: aws-cdk

The following CDK code

```
    const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, 'my-sqs-queue', {
      visibilityTimeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(300)
    });

    const role = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(this, "myrole", "arn:aws:iam::1234:role/myrole")

    const evtHandler = new lambda.Function(this, 'MyLambda', {
      code: lambda.Code.fromInline(`
        exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {
        console.log("EVENT: \n" + JSON.stringify(event, null, 2))
        return context.logStreamName
      }`),
      handler: 'index.handler',
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_8_10,
      role
    });

    evtHandler.addEventSource(new SqsEventSource(queue, {
      batchSize: 10 // default
    }));
```

will set up a lambda that polls SQS. Awesome! However, it also generates this CF

```
myrolePolicy99283C52:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - sqs:ReceiveMessage
              - sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility
              - sqs:GetQueueUrl
              - sqs:DeleteMessage
              - sqs:GetQueueAttributes
            Effect: Allow
            Resource:
              Fn::GetAtt:
                - sqseventloaderusw2tstF27FC9C7
                - Arn
        Version: "2012-10-17"
      PolicyName: snssqslambdaPolicy16AEE704
      Roles:
        - myrole
```

The problem is, `myrole` already has a policy that will allow those things. It also means the thing executing this script needs to have permissions to create/update Policies/Roles :(

Security in my org will not be super happy with allowing that kind of thing. Is there a way to stop it from generating policies and attaching them to roles?

Comment: I appreciate this was a couple of years ago, but how did you manage to solve this as I'm having the same issue with SNS and SQS adding default policies

Comment: i was able to use `autoCreatePolicy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I do my development, I usually have the docs setup in another window in my workspace. You just need to set the property `autoCreatePolicy` to false.

Per the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-sqs.Queue.html#autocreatepolicy

Comment: How do you set the autoCreatePolicy false?  I'm having the same trouble but with Buckets.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone coming across this later, setting the option `mutable` to **false** solved this for me.

So, in OP's example, the role would change to:

```
const role = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(this, "myrole", "arn:aws:iam::1234:role/myrole", {mutable: false})
```

For reference: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/4422

Comment: This has no relation to the original question that asks "how to stop creating new policies" instead of how to prevent an IAM role from having new policies attached to it.